# Как внедрить в проект гибкую систему логирования?

Tags: node.js, логирование

можно ли совместить:

1. вывод по log.levels (error, info, trace...)
2. вывод по `tag` как Log.d(TAG, "mess") из AndroidStudio
3. вывод многострочных логов (console.table)

по {2} вижу только фильтрацию файла лога через `grep`

но при таком подходе {2} и {3} будут конфликтовать, или придется в каждую строку таблицы добавлять `tag` что утяжелит получаемую информацию

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что можно как-то так:

1. Соблюдать единый формат логов, чтобы их можно было разбирать простой регуляркой.
2. Логировать [не в файл, а в поток.](https://12factor.net/logs)
3. Отправлять этот поток в какую-нибудь систему анализа логов (например, [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack)).

Фильтрация по уровням логирования, тегам и любым осмысленным признакам у вас появится за счет того, что каждая запись разбирается на составляющие и складывается в БД.

Не знаю, что делать с многострочными логами. Возможно, сериализовать в строку без переносов (используя `\n`), а при необходимости просмотра — десериализовать обратно. Общее правило такое: одна строка лога `==` одно событие.